# Subscribe from service example

Tags: ros, topic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

lets say that I have a service that needs some additional resources which is available via topic. Is there some example how this can be implemented?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52000/subscribe-from-service-example/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended way to do this is to have a subscription to the topic which stores the latest value in a persistent location. Then you can use that value in your service callback.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-01-13**:
I use this approach for saving images from camera, but the topic is output from some point cloud processing, that is computationally expensive. That is why I want to subscribe when the service is called.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-05**:
You can connect and disconnect at the beginning and end of the sevice.  But you will trade off latency for lower cpuusage.